# Why mapreduce secondary sorting is not on composite key's compareTo()?

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce

To perform secondary sort, we have to create a composite key which extends WritableComparable interface and implements compareTo().

In the "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide" book and almost all the blogs elsewhere shows sorting is happening based on compare() method of separate class (KeyComparator in the book) extending WritableComparator.

Both compare() and compareTo() have same logic. Since WritableComparator's compare() is used for sorting on composite keys, when is compareTo() of CompositeKey is actually used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sortcomparator is used to sort the map ouput. If you don't specify sortcomparator class it will use the comapreTo() method of the custom writable class. If sortcomparator is specified it uses that instead of custom writable's compareTo() method. But there is no advantage is using the default `compare(WritableComparable a, WritableComparable b)` which is same as that of the Writablecomparable comapreTo() method where it deserializes the records from the stream into objects and compares it. I think hadoop uses sortcomparator over default writablecomparable comapreTo() method because the former has a optimal compare() method `compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2)` where records from a stream are compared without deserializing it into objects.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vignesh. I read further in the book (3rd ed, page 268).

> ***Controlling Sort Order***
>
> 1. If the property mapred.output.key.comparator.class is set, either explicitly or by calling setSortComparatorClass() on Job, then an
>      instance of that class is used.
> 2. Otherwise,  keys  must  be  a  subclass  of  WritableComparable, and  the  registered comparator for the key class is used.
> 3. If there is no registered comparator, then a RawComparator is used that deserializes the byte streams being compared into objects and
>      delegates to the WritableComparable’s compareTo() method.

So IMO when key is not implementing WritableComparable interface or we are not satisfied with the implemented comparTo() method, then only sortcomparator makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Also i think sortcomparator is useful when we want to optimize our sort, by comparing the records without deserializing it into objects. But i have not seen this implemented in secondary sorting or in other places.

Comment: Vignesh, Got it. Thanks.